# Antd rendering <Menu /> component twice causes: Can't perform a React state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

For some reason, I need use my CustomMenu component in 2 different components but when I navigate between these 2 components or from another component, React gives:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

How do I solve this issue? Here is simple code to reproduce the error:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-playground-forked-1fxmqk?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

The error is being produced because you are rendering the menu itself at '/'. Then when you reach another route e.g. '/component-one' you render it again. An easy fix would be to place the menu like so:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <CustomMenu /> // By placing above the routes it always renders.
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ComponentOne />} path="/component-one" />
        <Route element={<ComponentTwo />} path="/component-two" />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

This makes it so the menu is always rendered. Then to stop it re-rendering again remove it from the components e.g:

```
const ComponentTwo = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Component Two</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Also good practise would be to place a component at '/' on the router for a landing location otherwise nothing will render unless already on one of the routes.

Comment: That's a good approach thanks! But I may need other component that I do not want <CustomMenu /> component to be there in the future. For example, in my /component-three I do not want to place <CustomMenu />.

Comment: I can conditionally render <CustomMenu />: If third component is rendered I can return null, but I'm not sure if it is not a good practice

Comment: If you didn't want the menu in every component, then you can remove the ```<CustomMenu /> ``` from App.js and just have it in each Component.

Comment: But it still causing the same error.

Comment: To prevent the error ```<CustomMenu />``` should be rendered either in App.js in the router or in each component once. It cannot be in both the router and components or the error will occur.

Comment: You are correct, but it doesn't make sense for me, I can rerender any component without the error I got here in this example. I created an issue to antd side in Github. Let's investigate this.